# How to Configure Walking Animation in Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

I have a walking animation that I have made in Blender. I can upload it into Unity(Most of it). How do I get it to start walking in Unity?

I'm assuming that there is a way to assign the walking action to a function and then call it from a script maybe?

Comment: This should help you get started https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation

Comment: Thanks dude. I really wasn't sure where to look for this.